# Override PayPal's Donation Reference/Donation ID Field

Tags: paypal

I have created a PayPal hosted donation button that works.  However, I would like to override the Donation ID that I inputted when I created the button via the HTML page.  My goal is to change what appears on the second line under "Purpose" that follows the word "Reference."  I am not able to determine the PayPal variable that will control what is on that line.   I can override the ITEM_NAME which is the first line shown under Purpose.   Anyone tackle this one?

Comment: Can you not change the Donation ID in the original button settings? (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/donation_buttons/#id08AAF0Q0NTA)

Comment: I can but I am offering sub categories to the user to target the donation and was hoping to have the sub category displayed in the reference line.  The sub category text is generated with the web page.